# Install matplotlib and pandas on shared hosting python from cpanel

Tags: cpanel, shared-hosting, uploading, python, django

When I upload my Django app, I have problem when I setup the python app configuration files. After adding `requirements.txt` gives me an error these libraries are not accepted:

- matplotlib==3.5.1
- pandas==1.3.5
- Pillow==9.0.0
- psycopg2==2.9.1
- scipy==1.7.3
- seaborn==0.11.2

Is there a solution?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about **web development** which is off-topic at Pro Webmasters. Web development questions may be asked at [so] but be sure to read their [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/help) before posting to ensure your question meets their guidelines.